# Add a condition for a function that has vectorized input

Tags: r, function, dataframe, conditional-statements, break

I have the following function with the variables:

```
b <- 1  ; d_uhpc <- 4 
L_joint <- 8  ; A_bar <- 0.31
A_s <- (A_bar/L_joint)*12
L_unb <- 16 ; f_t <- 1.2
E_s <- 29000 ; E_uhpc <- 8000 

ec <- function(x){
  theta <- x[3]
  eci <- seq(10^-3,1,10^-3)
  while (TRUE) {
    fc <- eci * E_uhpc
    c <- (sqrt(A_s^2 * E_s^2 * eci^2 + fc * A_s * E_s * b * d_uhpc *eci + b^2 * f_t^2 * d_uhpc^2) +
               b * f_t * d_uhpc - A_s * E_s *eci)/(b * fc + 2 * b * f_t)
    ec <- (-2*theta*c)/L_unb
    if (eci > abs(ec)) return("Error") else return(ec)
  }
}

# sample rows
strain.analysis <- read.table(text="
L S     theta
1  60 6 0.3876484
2  70 6 0.3650651
3  80 6 0.3619457
4  90 6 0.3089947
5 100 6 0.3131211
6 110 6 0.3479024", header=TRUE)
strain.analysis1 <- cbind(strain.analysis, vars = t(apply(strain.analysis,1,ec)))
```

The function does not understand the conditions correctly and just returns `ec` for all of the `eci` values regardless of the condition that it should only return `ec` when `eci < abs(ec)`

Below is an example of what I am trying to recreate in R.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing data, however your `A_bar` value is not defined so we cannot initialise  `c`. Also, using `c` as a variable is a bad idea as `c` is a very important base R primitive function.

Comment: @Croote Thank you so much, I just added `A_bar <- 0.31` to the original post. Do you suggest I remove `c` and just write a longer equation for `ec`. The final goal of this analysis is to get `c` value and check limits based on it. P.S. I made another edit to the original data too. in the function I updated the assigned column to `theta <- x[3]`

Comment: Thank you @Cole. I will make the increment smaller in my next edit! The original required increment had over 9999 haha! I thought I made it short enough :')

Comment: ec and eci are vectors of size 1000, what do you mean by eci<abs(ec)? all the values, any of them? Your current code only makes the comparison on the first value, this probably explain the problem you are having.

Comment: Why do you set `eci <- seq(10^-3, 1, 10^-3)`? From your flow chart, `eci` should be a single value, not a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I am thinking: your return statements in the `while` loop are incorrect as they exit the function `ec` and not only the `while` loop. I think your are after `break`. When I ran your code, with the `eci` as vector fixed, it only performed one loop for each row in the dataset.

Also, as mentioned before, `eci` cannot be a vector of length 1000. It has to start at 1E-6 and increment every loop with 1E-6 (per the figure). Your exit criteria are complicated and as we do not know what `0in` is it cannot be correctly reconstructed.

Finally, in `apply` you can call a user-defined function but you have to pass it something.

Having said that, is this what you are after?

```
b <- 1
d_uhpc <- 4 
L_joint <- 8
A_bar <- 0.31
A_s <- (A_bar/L_joint)*12
L_unb <- 16 
f_t <- 1.2
E_s <- 29000 
E_uhpc <- 8000 

eci <- 1E-6
ec <- function(x){
  #browser()
  theta <- x[3]
  while (TRUE) {
    fc <- eci * E_uhpc
    c <- (sqrt(A_s^2 * E_s^2 * eci^2 + fc * A_s * E_s * b * d_uhpc *eci + b^2 * f_t^2 * d_uhpc^2) +
            b * f_t * d_uhpc - A_s * E_s *eci)/(b * fc + 2 * b * f_t)
    ec <- (-2*theta*c)/L_unb
    if (eci > abs(ec)) break
    eci <- eci + 1E-6
  }
  
  if (c > d_uhpc | ((max(c(abs(ec), eci), na.rm = TRUE))/(min(c(abs(ec), eci), na.rm = TRUE))) - 1 > 0.05) return(NA_real_) else return(ec)
}


v <- apply(strain.analysis, 1, function(x) ec(x))
strain.analysis1 <- cbind(strain.analysis, v)
```

The code loops many times for each row of `strain,analysis` until the `break` condition is met. Based on the value of `ec` and `eci` the function returns either a value of `NA_real_`.

Here's how my output looks like:

```
> strain.analysis1
    L S     theta           v
1  60 6 0.3876484 -0.06845568
2  70 6 0.3650651 -0.06447493
3  80 6 0.3619457 -0.06392507
4  90 6 0.3089947 -0.05459143
5 100 6 0.3131211 -0.05531879
6 110 6 0.3479024 -0.06144967
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the guidance, I understand my issue with the eci vector, I was not sure how to include it in the loop! Thank you, I can choose your answer in 7 hours!

Comment: I have one question, if I `return(c)` at the end instead of `return(ec)`, the function still returns the `c` calculated from the `eci` increment that passed the `eci < abs(ec)` check, correct?

Comment: yes, that would be correct as `eci` is incremented after `break`. Note that R functions only return one object. If you need to return multiple objects, e.g. `ec` and `c`, combine them in a list and return the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more vectorized approach - it calculates all `ec` at once and then determines which `ec` meets the criteria. This means it is fast although it can use up more memory than @Paul van Oppen's solution.

```r
eci <- seq(10^-6,1,10^-6)
fc <- eci * E_uhpc
const <- (sqrt(A_s^2 * E_s^2 * eci^2 + fc * A_s * E_s * b * d_uhpc *eci + b^2 * f_t^2 * d_uhpc^2) +
            b * f_t * d_uhpc - A_s * E_s *eci)/(b * fc + 2 * b * f_t)

ec <- function(x){
  theta = x[3]
  ec = (-2*theta*const)/L_unb
  comp = eci > abs(ec)
  if (any(comp)) { ## at least one of our eci > abs(ec)
    wm = which.max(comp) 
    if (comp[wm] == FALSE) ##which.max(c(FALSE, FALSE)) will still return something. We need NA_real_ in this case
      return (NA_real_)
    else
      return(ec[wm])
  }
  else
    return(ec[length(x)])
}

cbind(strain.analysis, V = apply(strain.analysis,1,ec))
#>     L S     theta           V
#> 1  60 6 0.3876484 -0.06845568
#> 2  70 6 0.3650651 -0.06447493
#> 3  80 6 0.3619457 -0.06392507
#> 4  90 6 0.3089947 -0.05459143
#> 5 100 6 0.3131211 -0.05531879
#> 6 110 6 0.3479024 -0.06144967
```

Comment: I think maybe what I could be missing is that if ```eci < abs(ec)```, what is the result returned? Intended results would be nice.

Comment: I updated the original post to make it more clear! Sorry this is confusing!

Comment: Thanks for the edits. It would be better to include the expected results. I am editing one more time and while I believe I am addressing this, I am not a statistician and it seems like I am missing something. I just looked up the downward caret which seems to mean "OR".

Comment: I dont think this is doing what I need at all. It is not actually going through the eci used in that column and checking for the condition.

Comment: @MaralDorri please see edits. This is the vectorized approach I was going for in earlier edits.